# Sweetalert2 breaking my angular build. What to do?

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

While doing npm run build,

Got this error
ERROR in vendor.97ddeaba56b47c113f33.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>)

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot , code to know what is the issue

Comment: @Aravind I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think `sweetalert.js` file is breaking your build.

You can add `sweetalert.js` file in assets and provide its link in `index.html`

or you can use CDN link of  `sweetalert.js` file in `index.html`

Like this : `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`